# Is there a cleaner or simpler way to rewrite the code I made?

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and I'm currently taking an intro class in C++. My second lab tells me to replicate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tl5t.png).
I tried to make my code as simple as possible without getting too ahead of myself with things that are not yet covered in class. I just wanted to do something different so that I can learn more by myself. I had to look stuff up for hours before I asked my boyfriend for help. He is fluent in C++ yet I made sure not to do anything too advanced.

This is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cout << setw(39) << setfill('*') << "*" << endl;

    // center = (number of asterisks / 2) + (text size / 2)
    // round up on odd text sizes
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(28) << "Nathania Tasico\n" << setw(23) << "CSE 100\n" << setw(32) << "Welcome to C++ Programming" << endl;
    cout << setw(39) << setfill('*') << "*" << endl << endl;

    // Right justified = number of asterisks - text size 
    cout << "1. The sum of 2 + 3" << setfill(' ') << setw(19) << "= " << 2 + 3 << endl;
    cout << "2. The multiplication of 5*6" << setw(10) << "= " << 5 * 6 << endl;
    cout << "3. When I divide 15/7, the quotient" << setw(3) << "= " << 15 / 7 << endl;
    cout << "4. The remainder of 15 % 4" << setw(12) << "= " << 15 % 4 << "\n\n" << endl;

    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(37) << "This is the end of my first Program" << endl;
    cout << setw(24) << "Thank you!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know if there's a cleaner and/or simpler way to do this. I am submitting it as it is but I still want to learn the best way to do it so that I can learn more.

Thank you!

Comment: *"I just want to know if there's a cleaner and/or simpler way to do this."* Not really. That's probably what I would do--or at least something very close to that.

Comment: Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler. - Albert Einstein

Comment: There cleaner solution is just printing out the multiline text replacing setfill and setw with spaces/*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting. Basically this task cannot be solved. The teacher was giving the extpected output in a proportional font and the console output will be most likely monospaced. So, alignment and number of stars cannot fit.

Additionally. You have a bug in your solution. You should work width a overall width of 40, not 39. Otherwise you text is not fully reigt aligned.

So, now to possible solutions:

You could use the naive approach and simply output the expected text as a raw string.
Please do not use `using namespace std;`. You will find tons of hints here on stackoverflow that it should not be used.

Please see

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << R"(
****************************************
            Nathania Tasico
                CSE 100
       Welcome to C++ Programming
****************************************



1. The sum of 2+3                   = 5
2. The multiplication of 5*6        = 30
3. When I divide 15/7, the quotient = 2 
4. The remainder of 15 % 4          = 1



  This is the end of my first program
              Thank you!
)";

    return 0;
}
```

But that is too simple, because you want to learn about the usage of IO streams.

Then, next, we let the compiler calculate the mathematical result (this will happen at compile time, not at run time). Additionally, we learn, that C++ program input is unformatted, you can put in newlines wherever you want.

And with writing 2 string literals one after the other, they will be concatenated. So `"123" "456"` will be `"123456"`. Please also note that `std::endl` should not be used here. It flushes the output buffer every time (unnecessarily) and can safely be replaced by "\n" or '\n'.

Repeating `std::cout` in every line is also not necessary.

Next solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "****************************************\n"
                 "             Nathania Tasico\n"
                 "                 CSE 100\n"
                 "        Welcome to C++ Programming\n"
                 "****************************************\n\n\n\n"


                 "1. The sum of 2 + 3                 = " << 2 + 3
            << "\n2. The multiplication of 5*6        = " << 5 * 6
            << "\n3. When I divide 15/7, the quotient = " << 15 / 7
            << "\n4. The remainder of 15 % 4          = " << 15 % 4

      <<   "\n\n\n   This is the end of my first Program\n"
            <<   "               Thank you!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But, I guess, that your teacher wants to explain about manipulators.

Then the next solution would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::cout << std::setw(40) << std::setfill('*') << "" << '\n'

        // center = (number of asterisks / 2) + (text size / 2)
        // round up on odd text sizes
        << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(28) << "Nathania Tasico\n" 
        << std::setw(24) << "CSE 100\n"
        << std::setw(34) << "Welcome to C++ Programming\n"

        << std::setw(40) << std::setfill('*') << "" << "\n\n\n"

        // Right justified = number of asterisks - text size 
        << "1. The sum of 2 + 3" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(19) << "= " << 2 + 3
        << "\n2. The multiplication of 5*6" << std::setw(10) << "= " << 5 * 6
        << "\n3. When I divide 15/7, the quotient" << std::setw(3) << "= " << 15 / 7
        << "\n4. The remainder of 15 % 4" << std::setw(12) << "= " << 15 % 4 << "\n\n\n"

        << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(37) << "This is the end of my first Program\n"
        << std::setw(24) << "Thank you!\n";

    return 0;
}
```